# Не работают ссылки в древовидном меню

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

Всем привет. Почему то не работают ссылки в древовидном меню. Работают только ссылки подкатегорий. То есть в моем случае подкатегории есть только у категории "Вертолеты". Категории получаю из базы mysql. Меню сделано на jQuery (меню стащил из интернета, в js не соображаю). Гляньте пожалуйста, может ошибка где то в js файле? Другого я не предполагаю. Отключал файл CSS, проблема осталась.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub > a').click(function(){
       if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
         $('.sub ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }
        return false;
    });
         $('.mini-menu > ul > li > a').click(function(){
      $('.mini-menu > ul > li > a, .sub a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
   }),
         $('.sub ul li a').click(function(){
      $('.sub ul li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
   });


     $('.slider_slick_items').slick({
      prevArrow: '<i id="prev_arrow_slider" class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextArrow: '<i id="next_arrow_slider" class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
  });
  });
```

```html
php код (на всякий случай)



$tree = [];
    foreach ($data as $elem) {
        $tree[(int) $elem['parent_id']][] = $elem;
    }

    function treePrint($tree, $pid=0) {
        if (empty($tree[$pid])) {
            return;
        }
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($tree[$pid] as $k => $row) {
            if ($row['parent_id'] > '0') {
                $class = 'down_item';
            } else {
                $class = 'sub';
            }
            echo "<li class=\"$class\"><a href=\"?itemCard=$row[id]\">$row[category]</a>";
            if (isset($tree[$row['id']]))
                treePrint($tree, $row['id']);
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    
?>

<div class="mini-menu">
    
        <?php 
            treePrint($tree);
         ?>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что обработчик возвращает false, поэтому и не кликаются. Они работают на раскрытие подменю.

```
     $('.sub > a').click(function(){
         if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
           $('.sub ul').slideUp();
           $(this).next().slideToggle();
         }
          return false;
      });
```

Надо убрать класс sub там, где нужен переход по ссылке, а не раскрытие подменю. Либо убрать return false; в обработчике.

Comment: Мне нужно везде переход по ссылке, где нет подкатегорий. То есть мне уже на уровне php создать условие и если есть подменю, то оставить класс "sub", а где нет, то другой класс? Или в js файле что то отредактировать?

Comment: Уже на уровне php создать условие и если есть подменю, то оставить класс "sub", а где нет, то другой класс. Да, все верно.