# не срабатывает условие if

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Вывожу древообразное меню из mysql. По клику на категорию, выезжают подкатегории (если такие есть). Но если нет подкатегорий, то нужно чтобы категория стала ссылкой. Меню у меня на jQuery. Вывод меню на php. На php создал условие (17 строка), чтобы добавить класс "disable", если "parent_id" будет равно "id" категории. Но это условие не срабатывает. В чем моя ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub > a').click(function(){
       if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
         $('.sub ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }
        return false;
    });
         $('.mini-menu > ul > li > a').click(function(){
      $('.mini-menu > ul > li > a, .sub a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
   }),
         $('.sub ul li a').click(function(){
      $('.sub ul li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
   });


     $('.slider_slick_items').slick({
      prevArrow: '<i id="prev_arrow_slider" class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextArrow: '<i id="next_arrow_slider" class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
  });
  });
```

```html
php


<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error($link));
for ($data = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $data[] = $row);
$content = '';
$tree = [];
foreach ($data as $elem) {
    $tree[$elem['parent_id']][] = $elem;
}

function treePrint($tree, $pid=0) {
    if (empty($tree[$pid])) {
        return;
    }
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($tree[$pid] as $k => $row) {
        if ($row['parent_id'] == '0') {
            $class = 'sub';
        } else {
            $class = 'down_item';
        }
        echo "<li class=\"$class\"><a href=\"?itemCard=$row[id]\">$row[category]</a>";
        if (isset($tree[$row['id']])) {
            treePrint($tree, $row['id']);
        }
        echo '</li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';

}

?>

<div class="mini-menu">

    <?php 
        treePrint($tree);
     ?>
   
</div>
```

Comment: Ошибка в том, что вы не то сравниваете. К тому же, переменная class2 нигде не выводится.

Comment: А что нужно сравнить? переменную я если вывожу, то php ошибку выдает Undefined variable: class2.

Comment: Вероятно, $pid?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работают ссылки в древовидном меню](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/963926/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e)

Comment: Да, но в тот раз я создавал, думал что из за js не работает. Теперь проблема с php, не работает условие.

Comment: u_mulder, ничего не поменялось, если сравнивать с $pid.

Comment: `if ($row['parent_id'] == '0') {if ($row['parent_id'] == $row['id']) {вот фиг мы сюда попали...}}`

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста что нужно сравнить, чтобы добавить класс "disable" к категории, у которой нет подкатегорий? По логике вещей нужно сравнивать id категории и parent_id. Если они равны, значит у категории есть подкатегории.Или я что то не так говорю?

Comment: *что нужно сравнить, чтобы добавить класс "disable" к категории, у которой нет подкатегорий?* Получите это дело аки дополнительное поле прямо на уровне MySQL... а ещё лучше - покажите, как именно Вы там выгребаете дерево, каким запросом или процедурой (ну и версию MySQL укажите).

Comment: Отредактировал тему. Вставил полный код php страницы.  5.7.20 - MySQL Community Server (GPL).